# how to tell eclipse php linter that a variable exists?

Tags: php, eclipse, static-analysis, eclipse-pdt

EDIT: i updated from eclipse version 4.12.0 and PDT version 6.2.0.201812112302 to eclipse version 4.13.0M3 (pre-release), and PDT version 6.3.0.201908130957 (pre-release), and i can no longer reproduce the issue in the pre-release versions, now doing `/** @var variableType $variableName */` silence the error - i won't say for sure until the actual release comes out, but i'm pretty sure it's just a bug. (that has been fixed in dev but has not been released yet)

i have this really simple code:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);
namespace vaporfs;

/** @var array $config */
$config["db"]["dsn"] = "mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=vaporfs;charset=utf8mb4";
$config["db"]["username"] = "vaporfs";
$config["db"]["password"] = "ffaXIgcDAmXkB5iJXG";
```

that's all, just that. and the eclipse linter complains that $config does not exist before attmpting to use it:
 [image]

how do i tell the eclipse linter that variable $config does indeed exist?

(i really thought the answer was `/** @var array $config */`, but apparently not. or i'm doing it correctly but it's a bug in the linter perhaps?)

Comment: Do you import the variable? Or do you create it in this code snippet here?

Comment: @LLJ97 right now i am creating the variable right there, but i may create it elsewhere in the future, thus i don't want to declare/clear it here with a `$config=[];`, so i want eclipse to assume that the variable already exists here. an isset() guard seems to work, but i was hoping there's a better way than: ```if(!isset($config)){
    $config=[];
}
```

Comment: But then it is not a bug since PHP allows to work with variables that are not defined (obviously) but eclipse is still correct since the variable is not initialized. It's not pretty but eclipse is right about that, IMO. If you create it somewhere else and import it, eclipse will mark it as undefined since the linter ignores require/include statements.

Comment: @LLJ97 just to prove a point: now i made a new file with the content ```<?php namespace vaporfs;$config=["foo"=>"bar"];require_once('config.php');var_dump($config);``` - and eclipse still complains that $config is undefined, now eclipse linter is wrong, $config does exist. how do i tell the linter that $config already exists?

Comment: @LLJ97 btw i had the same problem in 2016, where the eclipse linter failed to realize that some variables existed. the solution in 2016 was to explicitly tell the linter that the variable existed with ```/** @var variableType $variableName */```, but it seems that does not work on modern versions of eclipse? so what's the modern way of doing it then? - just for the record i'm now using eclipse version 2019-06 (4.12.0), with PDT version `6.2.0.201812112302`, but i don't remember what version i used in 2016

Comment: As far as I can see you did the right thing but apparently they changed the linter to ignore such things. I would create a bug report since everybody points to `/** @var type name */` syntax but, as you said, eclipse ignores it.

Comment: @LLJ97 i can't reproduce it in current pre-release versions of eclipse, see the new `EDIT:` part of my post, yeah it's probably just a bug :)

Answer (score 1):

```
/** @var array $config */
```

is perfectly correct. Upcoming PDT 6.3 already support this.

Answer (score 0):

You are treating undefined variable as an array. The linter is giving you a warning and it is absolutely correct. It doesnt mean the code will not work though. It is just warning you that something might be wrong with it. The annotation is not going to help here. The variable is array the moment you assign to it as if it was an array anyway, so the annotation is not telling anything new.
Whether you include this file in another file that defined the variable in the scope in which config.php is included is irrelevant, because linter treats the file in isolation. You can as well include the file from a context where the variable is not defined, but that is out of reach of the linter. And so the linter prefers to warn you, because it sees it as possible to include the file in scope where the variable is not defined. It all comes down to the fact that you wrote the code in global scope and so it has side effects. Global scopes will mix together when you include more such files and the way it is mixed will depend on the order of inclusion.

Your options are:

1) Make sure it is defined in the config.php

```
$config = [];
//the rest of your code here
```

or

```
if (!isset($config)) {
  $config = [];
}
// rest of your code here
```

But you might want to also check that it is array and throw exception otherwise.

2) Remove the code from global scope with side effects, move it to function instead:

```
function createConfig(array $config = []) {
  // your code comes here
  return $config;
}
```

3) Live with the fact that you are sure you are including it the correct way and that the linter is warning you about something that might have happened but you made sure it is not.

IMO the best you can do is option 2 - avoid global scope side effects.

Comment: 1: if there is no way to silence a linter error you know is incorrect without changing the code, then that is a shitty linter. 2: it is probably just a bug, because i updated from eclipse version 4.12.0 and PDT version 6.2.0.201812112302 to eclipse version 4.13.0M3 (pre-release), and PDT version 6.3.0.201908130957 (pre-release), and i can no longer reproduce the issue in the pre-release versions, now doing ```/** @var variableType $variableName */``` silence the error - i won't say for sure until the actual release comes out, but i'm pretty sure it's just a bug

Comment: I wouldnt complain about the linter. Doing this in global scope is a shitty approach in the first place... And again it Is not a linter error, it Is a warning. The code works anyway. @hanshenrik